Homotopy push-out in the category of chain complexes
I'm trying to study the homotopy push out in the category of chain complex, for that, I first need to provide a model structure on  Fun$(D,\text{Ch}_k)$ where $D$ is the following category :
$$1\xrightarrow{i} 0 \xleftarrow{j} 2 $$
The model structure would be the projective one, I know how to prove that this defines a model structure when we consider  Fun$(D,C)$ with $C$ any category, but the proof is quite long ff you do it all by end as the cofibrations are characterized by :
$$f:F\to G \text{ is a cofibration } \iff f_0: F(0)\to G(0), f^1:F(0)\coprod_{G(0)} F(1) \to G(1),$$
$$f^2:F(0)\coprod_{G(0)} F(2) \to G(2) \text{ are cofibrations in  } \text{Ch}_k $$
So, I was wondering if there is an easier and quicker way to do it with the specific case of Fun$(D,\text{Ch}_k)$ ? I can't use any result on projective model structures, as I'm not supposed to have seen them. Any hints would be useful !

I mean, for the notion of "homotopy pushout" to make sense, you have to provide a model structure first. So what description of the model structure are you using? Or are you asking for an ad hoc explanation of what the "homotopy pushout" looks like without explaining why it actually is one in the model-theoretic sense?

@Thorgott That's my problem, I first want to proove that the projective structure provides a model structure on Fun(D,Ch_k) but my version of the proof is too long and I was wondering if I there was a quicker way to do it
